# How to use JSDom with Mocha?

Tags: mocha.js, jsdom

I am currently writing a test script using Mocha + Chai + JSDom:

**app_test.js**

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const fx = require('../fx.js');

describe('changeText()', () => {
    it('changes the text in the <p> element', function () {
        const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><p>foo</p>`);
        const document = dom.window.document;
        fx.changeText();
        expect(document.querySelector('p').innerText).to.equal("bar");
    })
});
```

**fx.js**

```
const changeText = () => {
    document.querySelector("p").innerText = "bar";
};

module.exports = {
    testInsert
};
```

But when I run `npm test` i get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of null
>         at Object.changeText (fx.js:2:5)

**UPDATE:**

I then tried changing **app_test.js** to:

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const fx = require('../fx.js');

describe('changeText()', () => {
    it('changes the text in the <p> element', function () {
        const dom = new JSDOM(`<body><p>foo</p><script>fx.changeText();</script></body>`, { runScripts: "dangerously" });
        expect(dom.window.document.querySelector('p').innerText).to.equal("bar");
    })
});
```

but am got this error:

> Error: Uncaught [ReferenceError: fx is not defined]

so, I then tried this:

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const fx = require('../fx.js');

describe('changeText()', () => {
    it('changes the text in the <p> element', function () {
        const window = (new JSDOM(``, { runScripts: "outside-only" })).window;
        const document = window.document;
        window.eval(`document.body.innerHTML = "<p>foo</p>";`);
        window.eval( fx.testInsert();
  expect(window.document.querySelector('p').innerText).to.equal("bar");       
    });
});
```

but get this error:

> ReferenceError: document is not defined
>         at Object.testInsert (fx.js:2:5)

so, I then tried this:

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const fx = require('../fx.js');

describe('changeText()', () => {
    it('changes the text in the <p> element', function () {
        const window = (new JSDOM(``, { runScripts: "outside-only" })).window;
        window.eval(`document.body.innerHTML = "<p>foo</p>";`);
        window.eval('window.fx = ' + fx);
        window.eval('fx.changeText();');
  expect(window.document.querySelector('p').innerText).to.equal("bar");
    });
});
```

but got this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
>         at eval ()

Comment: You have to pass `document` from the test to `changeText` since `document` is not a global variable (nor should it be under Node.js). Alternatively and preferably, run `changeText` in the window itself as a script, which means that it will have access to all the globals just like in a browser.

Comment: Thanks. How do I run changeText in the window - would you be able to provide an answer?

Comment: `dom.window.eval` *should* be what you are looking for, which requires `{ runScript: 'outside-only'` or `'dangerously' }`. Check out ["Executing Scripts"](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom#executing-scripts) in the JSDOM README.

Comment: Still struggling :(

Comment: Conceptually, JSDOM is basically an entire browser. When you execute `fx.testInsert()` you need to make `fx` available as a variable. To do this in a browser you would use a `<script>window.fx = { ... };</script>` element, which you can do in JSDOM with `'dangerously'` as well. Alternatively you can eval the script itself like `dom.window.eval('window.fx = ...')`, after which you can do `dom.window.eval('fx.testInsert();')`. The point is to use JSDOM just like a browser -- but with a few hooks.

Comment: so what should `...` be in your suggestion of `window.fx = ...` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146358/discussion-between-timothy-gu-and-joetidee).